# Filter lines from text file which fit to any element of an array in perl

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I have the following task to do and I wonder how to solve this issue most efficiently in Perl.
First, I have an array with 66 elements (chromosome:start:end) that looks like this

```
   my @array = qw( chr1:1566-1762  chr7:1695-1955 ....)
```

Next I have a file with a size of 50MB that contain this

```
   CHR \t START \t \END \tab \Pattern
   chr1 \t 1757 \t \2354 \t XM:Z:......H..H....H
   .
   .
```

I want to check every line of my file, whether position, start and end fit to any element in my array. The positions of the read in the file are not the same as in my array, but the start should be contained in the range. So for instance, I have a read that fit to the first element "chr1:1566-1662" by having the start position at 1757.

What would be your approach? I am glad about every hint and idea!

Comment: So, if I understand well, you only need to take in account the CHR column and the START column? Could you edit your question and add more datas to make some test.

Comment: Does your file actually contain the literal characters `\t` between every field or are you just trying to show that it's tab delimited?

Comment: It is tab delimited!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i would change the array from beeing array of string to some kind of array of structs (hashes). this makes some things more easy:

```
my @array = (
  { chr => "chr1", start => 1566, end => 1762 },
  { chr => "chr7", start => 1695, end => 1955 }
);
```

Further optimization may be thinkable (using chromosome as key in hash of range lists).

Then go through your file line by line and split each line and use this infos to check.

```
open FILE, fname || die "could not open file\n";

while(my $line = <FILE>){
  my @fields = split("\t", $line);
  chomp($fields[0]);  # remove whitespaces
  my $entry = {chr => $fields[0], start => $fields[1], end => $fields[2]};
  foreach $elem(@array){
    if(testMatch($entry, $elem)){
      print "found something";
    }
  }
}

close FILE;
```

The split may be more complex. Your example in the question is not very clear how it exactly looks like.

The testMatch routine simply returns 1 if the entries match

```
sub testMatch
{
  my $elem  = shift;
  my $range = shift;

  return    $elem->{chr}   eq $range->{chr}
         && $elem->{start} >= $range->{start} 
         && $elem->{start} <= $range->{end}
     #    && $elem->{end}   <= $range->{end} # not sure if the segment has to be entirely in the range
  ;
```

If you do not want to reformat your input `@array` you may create the reformatted programmatically before reading the file.
    }